# Execute shell cmd "echo test > /sdcard/testlog.txt" by executeShellCommand in UiAutomator 2.0

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I try to create a new file with shell cmd:

```
echo test > /sdcard/testlog.txt
```

But when I do it with executeShellCommand in UiAutomator 2.0.
The result will be only `echo "test > /sdcard/testlog.txt"` instead of create testlog.txt with content: test.

How can I execute such shell cmd?

The code is:

```
      String cmd = "echo test > /sdcard/testlog.txt";
      Log.i("AndroidUiTool2", mDevice.executeShellCommand(cmd));
```

The result is:

```
04-11 14:55:08.559 21520-21550/com.transsion.smoketest I/AndroidUiTool2: test > /sdcard/testlog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this code:**

manifests

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

testclass.java

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testlog.txt", true);    
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("test");    
bw.close();
```

Settings >App >Select your app >Enable Storage permission
It would write "test" in testlog.txt from your device

Comment: What if I need to write to the tested app's private storage, to set up initial shared preferences?

/data/data/PACKAGE/...

Does the app package running the UiAutomator have the necessary privileges? (root...?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
String cmd =  = "sh -c 'echo test > /sdcard/testlog.txt'";
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to write the file for me, while something like "touch /sdcard/testlog.txt" does ><